# Craft 3: Image transformation - grayscale

Tags: image-transforms, image

Are there any image manipulation options in Craft 3?

Like grayscale or so?
(what imager does for Craft 2: https://imager.vaersaagod.no/?img=5&demo=basic-image-adjustments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft 3 currently doesn't have image filter support, but it is on the list and you can track the Github issue here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1492